# React js code coverage

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.  I have developed a page using react js.  Now I want to do code coverage.  Pls help me.  Pls suggest which tool should I use for code Coverage for react code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) is a probably the best tool, but not as easy to use as libraries like [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/), which is simple and easy to use.

A good comparison of the two is provided [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/05/02/react-testing-jest-vs-mocha/).

Answer (score 0):

After the new update from them, **Jest** is the best option with **Enzyme** (for shallow rendering).